# How to translate text via Onesky translation API

Tags: api, translation

I have created a Onesky account and am trying to translate using their API.

Here is the sample request: https://api.oneskyapp.com/2/string/output?api-key=your-key&dev-hash=TheHash&platform-id=1&timestamp=1355555555

I am getting this output

```
{
"translation": {},
"md5": "99914b932bd37a50b983c5e7c90ae93b"
}
```

I am referring to http://developer.oneskyapp.com/api/v/2

How can I pass the translation string with the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving empty translation object because you have not translated anything.

1. Add some string in your test project
2. Translate it
3. Run the same api again (with updated dev-hash and timestamp)